# Lua ipairs not getting data from table

Tags: lua

I am a newbie to Lua. trying out some tutorials. Its my understanding that in Lua a table is a key value storage with any permissible LUA types as keys other than nil. ipairs is a way to iterate over a table until the ipairs hit a nil key.

I tried the below with the above understanding. But the second ipairs loop is not printing anything. 
The below snippet prints the keys and values.

```
   a ={}
  for i=1,1000 do
    a[i]=i
  end

  for i,data in ipairs(a)
  do
    print("key is:" .. i)
    print("value is " .. data)
    print("\n")
  end
```

This one is not printing anything

```
b={}
  b["a"]="a"
  b["name"]="test"
  b[10] ="b10"
  b["@"]="@@"

  for i,data in ipairs(b)
  do
    print("key is :" .. i)
    print("data is :" .. data)
    print("\n")
  end
```

any idea as what is wrong?

Full code that I am trying out.

```
function work_with_table()
  a = {}
  for i=1,1000 do
    a[i]=i
  end

  for i,data in ipairs(a)
  do
    print("key is:" .. i)
    print("value is " .. data)
    print("\n")
  end

  b={}
  b["a"]="a"
  b["name"]="test"
  b[10] ="b10"
  b["@"]="@@"

  for i,data in ipairs(b)
  do
    print("key is :" .. i)
    print("data is :" .. data)
    print("\n")
  end

end

work_with_table()
```

Edit 1:

I belive this  block creates a pair? ("a",t["a"]) ("name", t["name"])

```
b={}
  b["a"]="a"
  b["name"]="test"
  b[10] ="b10"
  b["@"]="@@"
```

Edit 2:

use ipair when the table's index is integer based. Otherwise use pairs for generic key, value looping. Thanks all for the help...

Comment: You use "ipairs" and don't try use "pairs"?

Comment: compare https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-ipairs and https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-pairs

Comment: I use the mnemonic *integer pairs* for `ipairs`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ipairs](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-ipairs)
iterates over the pairs (1,t[1])`, (2,t[2]), ..., up to the first nil value.

Comment: I belive this  block creates a pair? ("a",t["a"]) ("name", t["name"])  b={}
  b["a"]="a"
  b["name"]="test"
  b[10] ="b10"
  b["@"]="@@"

Comment: @GAK Read lhf's answer again -- he's talking about pairs where the key is a number from 1, not any random string as in your example.  For that, you need `pairs` instead.  BTW, `pairs` output is not ordered in any way.